# This Error is causing me a bit of a problem right now: Expected an Identifier

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

so i am basically trying to call date time from an api but this is giving me a bit of a problem

```
Text('${Util.getFormattedDate(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(snapshot.data?.dt??))}')
```

the data type of the date time is nullable but even when i git through that, it still showed me the expected an identifier error. the error is literally only for this text function and i need some help. i have tried everything but it still does not work

this is were Util is called from;

```
class Util{

  static String getFormattedDate(DateTime dateTime){

    return DateFormat("EEE, MMM d, y").format(dateTime);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On null cases it expects a value, because `fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch` doesn't accept null,

```dart
Text(
    '${Util.getFormattedDate(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(snapshot.data?.dt ?? 0))}')
```